# How to access Google KMS from Kubernetes Engine?

Tags: kubernetes, .net-core, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-kms

I had to move my .Net Core app from a Google App Engine to Google Kubernetes Engine because I need static IPs and sadly Google App Engine doesn't have that option.

I've managed to make a cluster and some pod, but in the logs I see:

```cs
Unhandled exception. Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode=PermissionDenied, Detail="Request had insufficient authentication scopes.")
   at Grpc.Core.Internal.AsyncCall`2.UnaryCall(TRequest msg)
   at Grpc.Core.Calls.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](CallInvocationDetails`2 call, TRequest req)
   at Grpc.Core.DefaultCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request)
   at Grpc.Core.Interceptors.InterceptingCallInvoker.<BlockingUnaryCall>b__3_0[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest req, ClientInterceptorContext`2 ctx)
   at Grpc.Core.ClientBase.ClientBaseConfiguration.ClientBaseConfigurationInterceptor.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest request, ClientInterceptorContext`2 context, BlockingUnaryCallContinuation`2 continuation)
   at Grpc.Core.Interceptors.InterceptingCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request)
   at Google.Cloud.Kms.V1.KeyManagementService.KeyManagementServiceClient.Decrypt(DecryptRequest request, CallOptions options)
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCall.GrpcCallAdapter`2.CallSync(TRequest request, CallSettings callSettings)
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCallRetryExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<WithRetry>b__0(TRequest request, CallSettings callSettings)
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCall`2.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<WithCallSettingsOverlay>b__1(TRequest req, CallSettings cs)
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCall`2.Sync(TRequest request, CallSettings perCallCallSettings)
   at Google.Cloud.Kms.V1.KeyManagementServiceClientImpl.Decrypt(DecryptRequest request, CallSettings callSettings)
   at Google.Cloud.Kms.V1.KeyManagementServiceClient.Decrypt(CryptoKeyName name, ByteString ciphertext, CallSettings callSettings)
   at Neo.Services.Kms.EncryptedFileInfo.CreateReadStream() in /app/Services/Kms/EncryptedFileInfo.cs:line 81
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load(Boolean reload)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList`1 providers)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
   at Neo.Services.Config.ConfigurationProvider.get_AppConfig() in /app/Services/Config/ConfigurationProvider.cs:line 27
   at Neo.Startup.LogAppChecks() in /app/Startup.cs:line 197
   at Neo.Startup.Run() in /app/Startup.cs:line 24
   at Neo.Program.Main() in /app/Program.cs:line 5
```

I've managed to find out that this problem exists because I cannot decrypt my `appsettings.json` file in Kubernetes. It worked in Google App Engine.

My guess is that's because GAE has set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable set by default.

I've found [that](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/encrypting-secrets#gcloud_4) article but it looks like it's describing something different.

How can I access Google KMS from Kubernetes Engine?

@update

The output from my node-pool describe:

```
config:
  diskSizeGb: 100
  diskType: pd-standard
  imageType: COS
  machineType: n1-standard-1
  metadata:
    disable-legacy-endpoints: 'true'
  oauthScopes:
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append
  serviceAccount: default
```

I've used this command to add scopes to my new node-pool

```sh
gcloud container node-pools create your-pool-name --zone europe-west1-b --cluster 
your-cluster-name --num-nodes 1 --scopes default,bigquery,cloud-platform,compute-rw,datastore,storage-full,taskqueue,userinfo-email,sql-admin
```

And now I get:

```cs
Unhandled exception. Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode=PermissionDenied, Detail="Permission 'cloudkms.cryptoKeyVersions.useToDecrypt' denied on resource 'projects/project-name/locations/global/keyRings/webapp/cryptoKeys/appsecrets' (or it may not exist).")
   at Grpc.Core.Internal.AsyncCall`2.UnaryCall(TRequest msg)
   at Grpc.Core.Calls.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](CallInvocationDetails`2 call, TRequest req)
   at Grpc.Core.DefaultCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request)
   at Grpc.Core.Interceptors.InterceptingCallInvoker.<BlockingUnaryCall>b__3_0[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest req, ClientInterceptorContext`2 ctx)
   at Grpc.Core.ClientBase.ClientBaseConfiguration.ClientBaseConfigurationInterceptor.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest request, ClientInterceptorContext`2 context, BlockingUnaryCallContinuation`2 continuation)
   at Grpc.Core.Interceptors.InterceptingCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request)
   at Google.Cloud.Kms.V1.KeyManagementService.KeyManagementServiceClient.Decrypt(DecryptRequest request, CallOptions options)
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCall.GrpcCallAdapter`2.CallSync(TRequest request, CallSettings callSettings)
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCallRetryExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<WithRetry>b__0(TRequest request, CallSettings callSettings)
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCall`2.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<WithCallSettingsOverlay>b__1(TRequest req, CallSettings cs)
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCall`2.Sync(TRequest request, CallSettings perCallCallSettings)
   at Google.Cloud.Kms.V1.KeyManagementServiceClientImpl.Decrypt(DecryptRequest request, CallSettings callSettings)
   at Google.Cloud.Kms.V1.KeyManagementServiceClient.Decrypt(CryptoKeyName name, ByteString ciphertext, CallSettings callSettings)
   at Neo.Services.Kms.EncryptedFileInfo.CreateReadStream() in /app/Services/Kms/EncryptedFileInfo.cs:line 81
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load(Boolean reload)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList`1 providers)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
   at Neo.Services.Config.ConfigurationProvider.get_AppConfig() in /app/Services/Config/ConfigurationProvider.cs:line 27
   at Neo.Startup.LogAppChecks() in /app/Startup.cs:line 197
   at Neo.Startup.Run() in /app/Startup.cs:line 24
   at Neo.Program.Main() in /app/Program.cs:line 5
```

And after I added Google KMS Decypt/Encrypt role to service account it works!

Thanks @sethvargo

**IT WORKS NOW**

Comment: When you create your cluster, you need to make sure the node pool has the `cloud-platform` oauth scope. More here: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/access-scopes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message reads:

> Request had insufficient authentication scopes

Therefore it needs scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform` added.

The service account needs IAM role `roles/cloudkms.cryptoKeyEncrypterDecrypter`.